# I want to save data into sql server from eclips is there any solution?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I want to save data into sql server from eclips is there any solution?
Is it possible with web service or json..
i have made one asp.net website and made web service for method...and cath that data into eclips by json...so now how to cath data from elips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am used belove code for get data from asp.net SOAP webservice in android try this**

```
 public static String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "http://myweb.com/";
public static String SOAP_METHOD_GetQuestionAnswer = "GetQuestionAnswer";

// GetQuestionAnswer Method
public static String GetQuestionAnswer(String GameIDValue, String QuestionIDValue) {
    String responce = null; 

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD_GetQuestionAnswer);

    PropertyInfo GameID = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo QuestionID = new PropertyInfo();

    GameID.setName("gameid");
    GameID.setValue(GameIDValue);

    QuestionID.setName("queid");
    QuestionID.setValue(QuestionIDValue);

    request.addProperty(GameID);
    request.addProperty(QuestionID);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL);
    try {
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_GetQuestionAnswer, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive LoginResult;
        LoginResult = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("=================GetQuestion Results: "+LoginResult);
        System.out.println(LoginResult.toString());
        responce = LoginResult.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return responce;
}
```

Comment: i want to pass data from android to web service

Comment: which web service used , rest full or soap ?

Comment: ok try above code i am used this in my android application.

Comment: yes i hv done the same dear...bt now i want to send data from android to server

Comment: i have a list of data that i want to save into sql server

Comment: @shivanipatel can you pls tell me whats you way of sending the data to the server, are you using SOAP, XML, JSON, or HTTP POST...??

Comment: @shivanipatel there is no method to save direct data to ms sql server.you can use webservice to save data.

Comment: ...thanx i m trying in this way only

Comment: Why should a developer use web services instead of direct connections to a db?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db

Answer (score 0):

In android you can create a `JSON object` and `POST` in to your `asp web service`, which eventually send data to your `remote sql database`.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("val1",val1);
obj.put("val2",val2);
obj.put("val3",val3);
```

Comment: @shivanipatel hey dear i check my answer it will help regarding your problem..

Comment: @shivanipatel use List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;