# Direct insert data in mysql data in android

Tags: android

I want to save insert data into MYSQL DataBase ,without using any webservice .is there any way to solve my.. or There is not possible to insert data directly into DataBase .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should not be doing that. You will need to store the database password and user in your app and also expose the db outside local host. With a little decompiling your db can be accessed by anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DVK answered why you shouldn't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db)

In short, Yes you *can* insert data into a database directly without using webservice. However you would have very little to gain as mention by DVK answer.

Beside, the webservice are easy to make. There are a lot framework that making webservice real easy, and will do most of the heavily lifting. I'm not sure for mysql, but [.NET Framework contains some excellent library.](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)