# Can Android connect directly to MySQL without PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

1. I want to connect to MySQL remote database from android **but** I don't want to send request to php, I want a straight connection to MySQL without making request to php, so in my opinion it will be more fast and I will get everything i need from mysql remote db table, but as far as I google only tutorials on how to connect through request to php. Is it even possible to do what I want?
2. If the first one isn't possible, could Android have local database SQLite in which straight away in android code I can wire queries to that db, but is it possible to write queries inside android code to remote mysql database?

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT, we have **markup** on this site. You should also leave out thanks and non-question related material: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)):

Comment: In practice, you will always need more security controls than MySQL will give you - hence the need for a server-side layer. If it gets slow then you can optimise your queries or upgrade your hardware (but don't optimise unless you need to).

Comment: @halfer After re-visiting this question, I realized that your comment was more of an answer than the one I had posted!  I just quoted your comment in the answer so that it doesn't get lost.  Hope that's ok, if not just roll it back.  Cheers!

Comment: No worries @Daniel, that's fine `:-)`.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. In this article you could find info about [how to connect to MySQL in Android without PHP](https://medium.com/@joseds./xampp-db-connection-with-android-e7b682fc699c)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044910/how-to-make-mysql-connector-j-working-on-android

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly recommended that you don't do this.

See this post: [Direct insert data in mysql data in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639937/direct-insert-data-in-mysql-data-in-android)

... and this post:  [Why should a developer use web services instead of direct connections to a db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db)

**Edit**:  The comment from @halfer is very informative, so quoting it here:

> In practice, you will always need more security controls than MySQL
>   will give you - hence the need for a server-side layer. If it gets
>   slow then you can optimise your queries or upgrade your hardware (but
>   don't optimise unless you need to).

Comment: based on your answer and the link you've included, i think you should study more what is the difference between an answer and an advise

Answer (score 1):

1.
Yes, it is possible. I use Delphi XE5 FMX and MyDAC from DEVART.