# Provide connectivity to a database where actual data is not provided but only table and field names that a user can connect to, to run calculations

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite

I have a specific dataset that I want a client to have access to, but only in a manner that they cannot see/query the data, but can reference table and fields for their calculations.  A well documented user guide will be provided.  Is this technically possible?  If so, how can I go about doing this.

Comment: "*reference table and fields for their calculations*" - Waht does it mean?

Comment: For example:  in a table called price, I have fields called product name,  retail price, wholesale price.  I don't want the customer to be able to see the data in these fields.  However the customers tech department should be able to join a product name to the product to name in my table and get a price for wholesale or retail based on the data contained in my tables.  They cannot however query the tables I have and the data will reside on my server.

Comment: You may want to hide that database completely and instead expose services for your customers in whatever limited scope you need.

Comment: Thank you PM 77.  I am happy to research it more, however I didn't know the exact technical term for hiding the database and exposing services in my limited scope.  Am I correct in understanding that I'd need to go through hiding a db and exposing services?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db