# Do I have to create a web service between my app and database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

Is it a good idea to create a webservice between my app and a database? I use a lot of database stuff within my app - so what do you think? In a later version of my app I want to let partner connect to my service to insert something like user ratings etc.

Comment: Do you have to? No. Is it a good idea? Yes.

Comment: Thank you, I think that as well but a friend of mine said its useless in this case

Comment: Then ask *them* why they say that, and see if you agree with their reasons.

Comment: Perhaps some more information about your app might help us form more educated responses.

Answer (score -1):

It is a good idea to make one because it helps make your app very **secure**. Moreover, it also reduces the connection load to the database. When you have your web service, it can keep the connection running.

I was going to write a long description oh why you need to use web service but found someone else already answered it for you in detail: [Follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db)