# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/mysql/jdbc/configs/maxPerformance.properties'

Tags: android, mysql, database-connection

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'com/mysql/jdbc/configs/maxPerformance.properties'
```

when I tried to build my gradle in Android Studio I am tring to use MySQL as database in my project

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Also, please don't add screenshots of code -add it into the question. And add the logs (see [mcve])

Answer (score 0):

You linked the mysql-connector-java dependency twice. I would suggest linking the dependency via:

```
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.45'
```

This dependency is available at jcenter (https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/mysql:mysql-connector-java).

**However I would not recommend connecting directly to SQL database. I would prefer writing a REST service instead. The reasons why you should not use direct connection to database are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142070/why-should-a-developer-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-connections-to-a-db).**